# Returning to calendar in month view always goes back one month,

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, local-storage, fullcalendar-5

I'm having difficulty getting my users to return to the month they were working in after a change is made.

Currently, I have a function that initializes the calendar.

```
var iv = localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultView") || 'timeGridWeek';
var id = localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultDate") || new Date;
```

```
        initialView: iv,
        initialDate: id,
        datesSet: function (dateInfo) {
            localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultView", dateInfo.view.type);
            localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultDate", dateInfo.startStr);
        },
```

What is strange is that, when the user is in any view other than monthView, everything works fine. But when in monthView, when they return to the calendar, it displays the previous month.

Comment: Demo which reproduces the issue: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxdXpON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you've got with the month view is that the "start" date of any month view in fullCalendar is often a day or two *before* the start of the month. For example if you open fullCalendar month view for the current month (August 2021) you'll see that the first date displayed on the calendar is 27th July. So if you log `dateInfo.startStr` as you're adding it to the localStorage, you'll see that for August 2021 (again for example) it'll save 27th July 2021.

However if you then set that as the initial date next time you load the calendar, fullCalendar then sets the view to the month which the date occurs in.

To solve this, rather than using the date provided directly in the datesSet callback, you can get the "currentStart" value from the view object, which is the start of the interval the view is trying to represent, rather than the start of the visible time period. This distinction only really applies in month view, so it has no impact on the already-working behaviour other views.

Change the setItem call to this:

```
localStorage.setItem("fcDefaultDate", dateInfo.view.currentStart);
```

As this is a JS Date object which then gets serialised, rather than an ISO string, you need to explicitly parse it when reading it out again, so another small change is required:

```
var id = Date.parse(localStorage.getItem("fcDefaultDate")) || new Date();
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/JjNrMBd

Documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I made the changes and get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Date.parse is not a function

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. It works in the CodePen demo, and that function has been supported in every browser since day 1. Are you testing with some sort of very obscure browser??

Answer (score 1):

It's because the month starts from 0, not 1. so January is "0" and February is "1".

Comment: I assumed it was a zero-based array, but why would the script expose the value that is saved as a zero-based array then use the value as a 1 based array when restoring the view? Where can I compensate and increment the value so it restores properly? What datatype is

```
dateInfo.startStr
````

Comment: @EddieGrimaldi `dateInfo.startStr` is a string. The name gives you a clue, the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) states that explicitly and you can always test with typeof(). Not really sure why you need to ask that.

Comment: Anyway this isn't the problem...see my answer for the real explanation.